# Parse XML data from URL in Bot Builder

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

May I ask about how to Parse the XML data from URL in Bot Builder?

I had try xml2js but did not work and also xmlhttprequest.

Here with my source code

```
   var xmldata = "https://mvponduty.mvpondutyonmicrosoft.com/xml/data.xml";
   console.log(xmldata);
   parseString(xmldata, function (err, result) {
    // Result contains XML data in JSON format
    context.sendActivity(result.toString());
   });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests for you on my side , and you can try the code below to get a xml from URL and parse it to JSON in bot :

```
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            var xmlURL = 'https://andyapi2.azurewebsites.net/test/test.xml';
            let xml2js = require('xml2js');
            const axios = require('axios');
            var resp = '';
            await axios.get(xmlURL)
                .then(response => {
                    xml2js.parseString(response.data, function(_err, result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        resp = result;
                    });

                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });      
            await context.sendActivity(resp.note.body[0]);
            await next();
        });
```

XML data :

```html
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: If the URL is RSS?

Comment: Hi @EngSoonCheah , I am so sorry I am not so familiar with RSS , if you have issues about RSS , could you pls post another question and I'll look into it once I see it. Btw , if my post solved your issue , could you pls mark it so that it will help others who has similar issue ? Thanks !